# switching docking station between desktop and laptop with usb-c (no kvm)

Tags: usb, laptop, multiple-monitors, docking-station, usb-c

I'm relatively new to docking stations and all that Jazz and obsessed with USB-C.

Right now I have a macbook pro that I use for work and  can connect to my three monitor setup via docking station.

The issue is, that this docking station is not usable with my current desktop, since it has no usbc ports. If I want to switch over to my desktop I have to manually move all three cables and other devices from the docking station into the desktop (a real pain) and a KVM would not work since a good number of my devices are wireless as well...

I saw that some motherboards/desktops have usb-c ports. Could I use these in a similar way to my macbook pros usb-c ports? If so, what features/key words let me know that it's not just a USB-c port put on there for yuk yuks.

Also, I've attached some awful dia-diagrams to illustrate kinda what I want[image]

Comment: If your desktop PC does not have any USB Type-C ports, get an add-on PCIe card with USB-C port. This will solve your problem with one cable switch.

Comment: Would that allow me to just plug in the dock and all my peripherals would just tag along? I'm just mildly distrustful of everything magically moving over haha

Comment: When you disconnect Type-C cable from one PC and plug it into another PC, each and every device connected to downstream ports will be enumerated and re-connected, with possible exception of your displays. If the displays were connected over DisplayLink bridges (inside the docking station), they will be functional as well.

Comment: Okay. That's a helpful insight. I'll lookup the doc my company sent me and see if the displays use displaylink bridges